# Typescript Combine Javascript Output into Single File bundles up JS files also

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

My project has an app.js node file in root, and typescript files for the client side in in a sub folder, set to spit out an all.js on save. After a reinstall, typescript suddenly started concatenating app.js to the bottom of the amalgamation.

I've tried adding False into the njsproj file without any luck.

Any ideas?

EDIT>

The problem went away after installing an earlier version Node JS tools for visual studio. I have no idea why.

Comment: it would help if you could share more of your folder structure and the tsconfig.json file. :)

Comment: @toskv There are too many variables to share, but see my edit for solution.

Comment: tsc doesn't require node to run.. are you using gulp or grunt to move files about during the build maybe? gulp or grunt versions might need specific node versons.